# Using gstreamer rtsp server with multi streams & camera

Tags: c++, gstreamer, rtsp

I have some confusion while using GStreamer, so I have a question like this.

First, I wrote an example code by referring to [gst-rtsp-server (github)](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/tree/master/examples)

However, My actual environment is a little different from the example.

In these examples, It appears to use one camera or stream.

But I use multiple IP Cameras(Maybe 2~5) and then I use multi-stream(1~2) from each camera.

[Example]

Server IP : 192.168.0.200

Camera 1 : 192.168.0.100:554 -> has /stream1, /stream2

=> rtsp://admin:1234qwer@192.168.0.200/MyStream1_1

=> rtsp://admin:1234qwer@192.168.0.200/MyStream1_2

Camera 2 : 192.168.0.101:554 -> has /stream1, /stream2, ..

=> rtsp://admin:1234qwer@192.168.0.200/MyStream2_1

=> rtsp://admin:1234qwer@192.168.0.200/MyStream2_1

...

As a result, all of these streams are threated as opencv matrix and passed to udpsink via encoding.

```
// write matrix for stream to GStreamer udpsink
void GStreamerServer::storeStream(int __camera, int __stream)
{
    ...
    // port : 5000 + (camera index * 10) + (stream index)
    // ex. camera1's stream1 = 5000
    // ex. camera1's stream2 = 5001
    // ex. camera2's stream2 = 5011
    sprintf(sz_url, "appsrc is-live=true ! "
                    "queue ! "
                    "videoconvert ! "
                    "video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! "
                    "nvvidconv ! "
                    "omxh264enc qp-range=35,35:35,35:-1,-1 ! "
                    "video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream ! "
                    "h264parse ! "
                    "rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=1 ! "
                    "udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=%d", port);
}

// running gstreamer rtsp server in main thread
void GStreamerServer::threadFunc_runServer(std::vector<int> __stream_per_camera)
{
    GMainLoop           *loop    = nullptr; // release ok
    GstRTSPServer       *server  = nullptr; //
    GstRTSPMountPoints  *mounts  = nullptr; // release ok
    GstRTSPMediaFactory *factory = nullptr; //
    GstRTSPSessionPool  *session = nullptr; // release ok

    GstRTSPAuth         *auth    = nullptr; // release ok
    GstRTSPToken        *token   = nullptr; // release ok
    gchar               *basic   = nullptr; // release ok

    gst_init(NULL, NULL);
    
    loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

    session = gst_rtsp_session_pool_new();
    gst_rtsp_session_pool_set_max_sessions(session, 255);

    server = gst_rtsp_server_new();
    g_object_set(server, "service", "8554", NULL);

    // alloc auth .. so don't care below code
    ...

    // create mounts
    mounts = gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points(server);

    // get camera & stream count
    int camera_count = __stream_per_camera.size();
    if (camera_count == 0)
        camera_count = 1;

    // <<<<< This is my Question >>>>>
    guint64 udp_buffer_size = 3840 * 2160 * 3;// 3: rgb

    constexpr uint64_t timeout = 10 * 1000 * 1000;

    for (int _camera = 0; _camera < __cameras.size(); _camera++)
    {
        int channel_count = __cameras.at(_camera);

        for (int _stream = 0; _stream < channel_count; _stream++)
        {
            char udpsrc_pipeline[1024];
            memset(udpsrc_pipeline, 0, sizeof(udpsrc_pipeline));

            char udpsrc_stream[32];
            memset(udpsrc_stream, 0, sizeof(udpsrc_stream));
            
            int updsink_port_num = get_port_number(_camera, _stream);
            snprintf(udpsrc_pipeline, sizeof(udpsrc_pipeline), 
                    "("
                    "udpsrc "
                    "name=pay0 "
                    "port=%d "
                    "buffer-size=%lu "
                    "caps= \"application/x-rtp, "
                            "timeout=%lu, "
                            "media=video, "
                            "clock-rate=90000, "
                            "encoding-name=H264, "
                            "payload=96\""
                    ")"
                    , updsink_port_num, udp_buffer_size, timeout
            );
            

            factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new();

            gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch(factory, udpsrc_pipeline);

            gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared(factory, TRUE);

            snprintf(udpsrc_stream, sizeof(udpsrc_stream), 
                    "/MyStream%d_%d", _camera + 1, _stream + 1);

            gst_rtsp_mount_points_add_factory(mounts, udpsrc_stream, factory);

            // add auth
            gst_rtsp_media_factory_add_role (factory, "admin",
                GST_RTSP_PERM_MEDIA_FACTORY_ACCESS, G_TYPE_BOOLEAN, TRUE,
                GST_RTSP_PERM_MEDIA_FACTORY_CONSTRUCT, G_TYPE_BOOLEAN, TRUE,
                NULL);

            gst_rtsp_server_set_auth(server, auth);
        }
    }

    guint server_id = gst_rtsp_server_attach(server, NULL);
    g_main_loop_run(loop);

    // release
    ..
    for (int _camera = 0; _camera < __cameras.size(); _camera++)
    {
        int channel_count = __cameras.at(_camera);
        for (int _stream = 0; _stream < channel_count; _stream++)
        {
            char udpsrc_stream[32];
            memset(udpsrc_stream, 0, sizeof(udpsrc_stream));
            snprintf(udpsrc_stream, sizeof(udpsrc_stream), 
                    "/MyStream%d_%d", _camera + 1, _stream + 1);
            gst_rtsp_mount_points_remove_factory(mounts, udpsrc_stream);
        }
    }
    g_object_unref(mounts);

    ...
}
```

[Question]

Q1. In fact, the above code currently works without any problems(with 4 camera, total 6 stream). However, I would like to get confirmation that the above method is the right method.

In the current code, I created several factories(gst_rtsp_media_factory_new) with one GstRTSPMediaFactory.

If so, is this not memory leak?

Should I declare GstRTSPMediaFactory as many as all streams and **new** each?

Q2. In buffer size(udp_buffer_size), I think this size is frame's max size per stream.

I use various resolutions from D1(740x480) to FHD(1920x1080)

However, I have allocated a 4K buffer size for future scalability.

But I found out that the size here is not the image size, but the kernel UDP buffer size.
(refer [here](https://thiblahute.github.io/GStreamer-doc/udp-1.0/udpsrc.html?gi-language=c))

In fact, when I reduced this size, there were cases where some streams experienced frequent disconnected or none connected.

Is this size allocated for each facotry created by gst_rtsp_media_factory_new?

Since english is not my first language, I'm sorry that there may be a sentence that don't understand. If you give me feedback, I'll edit or respond as soon as possible.

Thank you!